# Confusion with constructor function in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Why I am able to use properties in constructor function without being defined in the class, Please read my code below.

```
<?php
class TV
{
 public function __construct($m, $v)
 {
  $this->model = $m;
  $this->volume = $v;
 }
}

$tv_one = new TV("Samsung", 6);
echo $tv_one->model."<br><br>";
echo $tv_one->volume;
?>
```

Have a look at this code also. I am able to share private property outside the class. Just go throuh this code-

```
<?php
class TV
{
 private $model = "Samsung";
 private $volume = 2;

 public function volumeUp()
 {
  return $this->volume++;
 }

 public function volumeDown()
 {
  return $this->volume--;
 }
 public function __construct($m, $v)
 {
  $this->model = $m;
  $this->volume = $v;
 }
}
class PlasmaTv extends TV 
{
 public $plasma = true;
 public function hello()
 {
  return "I am new " . $this->model . " and my default volume is " . $this->volume . ".";
 }
 public function __construct($m, $v, $p)
 {
  $this->model = $m;
  $this->volume = $v;
  $this->plasma = $p;
 }
}
$plasma = new PlasmaTv("Soni", 6, true);
echo $plasma->model."<br><br>";
echo $plasma->volume."<br><br>";
echo $plasma->plasma;
echo $plasma->hello();
?>
```

Comment: The first example does make sense to me. PHP is a dynamic language, you can define properties in a dynamic manner if you chose to. Per default those are public. Which explains why you can access the from outside the class.

Comment: In the second example those two properties are declared as private in class `TV`. That means class `PlasmaTV` cannot see them. Therefore `$this->model` will _again_ access a dynamically created property.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't require you to declare properties. Just assigning to a property will create it as a public property. So when the first constructor does:

```
$this->model = $m;
```

that creates a `model` property in the object.

In your `PlasmaTv` class, the `model` and `volume` properties are not the same as the ones in the parent class `TV`, because the properties in the parent are private and can't be accessed in the child. If you do:

```
$plasma->volumeUp();
echo $plasma->volume;
```

it will print `6`, not `7`, because `volumeUp()` incremented a different property than the public property in `PlasmaTv`.

If you want to share the properties between the child and parent, declare them `protected`. But then you won't be able to use `$plasma->volume` from outside the classes.

Comment: So, what about this keyword, I am reffering to the class properties with "this" keyword?

Comment: You can only refer to the class properties that you have access to. Since the child class doesn't have access to the parent class's private properties, `$this->model` creates a new property in the child class.